# Extracting Byte values from Azure Table Storage

Tags: python, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I am writing a python script to query data from an Azure Table Storage.

The data which I want to extract is of type Binary (The info is serialized and stored)

When I run the code using **entity['BodyChunk01]**  I get the value back as

`'BodyChunk01': <azure.data.tables._entity.EntityProperty object at 0x0DDFFB10>`

(The name of the column is BodyChunk01)

and when I use **entity['BodyChunk01'].value** as mentioned in another question on stackoverflow, it returns the deserialized json data but I want the actual serialized value that is stored as you can see in the screenshot below

[image: Sample Byte Data]

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're trying to accomplish is not possible. I looked up the SDK code [`here`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/ea8a73b11498ed821b3ea67d75fc27adfd1294e3/sdk/tables/azure-data-tables/azure/data/tables/_deserialize.py#L225) and it seems the SDK is forcefully doing the conversion based on the code [`here`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/ea8a73b11498ed821b3ea67d75fc27adfd1294e3/sdk/tables/azure-data-tables/azure/data/tables/_common_conversion.py#L71).

```
def _decode_base64_to_bytes(data):
    if isinstance(data, six.text_type):
        data = data.encode("utf-8")
    return base64.b64decode(data)
```

You may want to raise an issue here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/issues and bring this to SDK team's attention.

Binary data is converted into a `Base64 encoded string` and is then saved. What you would need to do is do a Base64 decode to get the byte array.

I am not well versed with Python but you can do something like this:

```
import base64
decodedBytes = base64.b64decode(entity['BodyChunk01'].value)
decodedStr = str(decodedBytes, "utf-8")
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but when I do entity['BodyChunk01'].value I don't get the byte string like the one in the screenshot, I get the json output, so it automatically decodes it.

But what I want is the Byte array like the one in the screenshot

Comment: Oh...may be I misunderstood. So what you're saying is that SDK is automatically decoding the content and you don't want that to happen. Correct? What's the SDK you're using?

Comment: yes when I use .value it automatically decodes it and I dont want that to happen, I want the actual byte array. 

I am using the azure.data.tables sdk for python

Comment: Updated my answer. HTH.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want the entity in a raw format you can include a header to not return OData types and this will pass by the deserialization. Ints, floats, booleans are converted to their respective types, but a binary entity property will be returned as the raw string. Here's a code snippet:

```py
headers = {'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata'}

received_entity = table_client.get_entity(
    row_key=entity['RowKey'],
    partition_key=entity['PartitionKey'],
    headers=headers
)

print(received_entity['BodyChunk01'])
```

Disclaimer: I work on the Azure SDK for Python team